# JQuery Facebook like AutoSuggest triggered by "@"

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

I'm looking for a JQuery (or other framework) plugin, kind of working like the Facebook status message text box.

What it should do:

- Allow text to be typed freely without triggering the AutoSuggest (as opposed to normal AutoSuggest boxes)
- Show the AutoSuggest, when triggered by a certain character, such as '@'.

Actually, it should work exactly like the one in FaceBook ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Search_SuggestTextBox.aspx

The good thing about this library is that it is triggered by the text input's **onkeyup**. This means you can alter their provided JS function to check for the correct key sequence

Maybe something like this:

```
var shiftDown=false; //Track if SHIFT was the last key pressed.

function searchSuggest(e) 
{
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (key==40 || key==38)
    {
        shiftDown=false;
        scrolldiv(key); 
    }
    else if (key == 16) // SHIFT WAS PRESSED
    {
        shiftDown=true;
    }
    else if (key == 50 && shiftDown) // 2 WAS PRESSED
    {
        if (searchReq.readyState == 4 || searchReq.readyState == 0) 
        {
            var str = escape(document.getElementById('txtSearch').value);
            strOriginal=str;
            searchReq.open("GET", 'Result.aspx?search=' + str, true);  
            searchReq.onreadystatechange = handleSearchSuggest;
            searchReq.send(null);
            shiftDown=false; 
        }
    }  
    else 
    {   
        shiftDown=false; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the carot position, can that be retrieved somehow?

Comment: Nevermind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area and http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caret

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully by now you (OP) have been able to utilize Dutchie432's answer to create a solution that you are content with. But if you, or anyone else who happens to stumble upon this, haven't, or have and are perhaps are looking for a robust, ready-to-use solution...

...It looks like [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator) is exactly what you're looking for: it is a jQuery plug-in which enables clients to create highlighted references to ("mentions") to predefined entities in text areas. It is mantained by this guy right here :) .

Unlike similar plug-ins, Mentionator provides the following options which provides options which, as you requested, enable it to function exactly like Facebook's tagging facility:

```
doesRecognizeDelimitedSubstrings: 
    A boolean which, if defined as true, will allow the external value
    of a mention, herein called "mentionExternalValue", to sustain
    modifications so long as the result of each such modification 
    is in mentionExternalValue.split(delimValue)

delimValue: 
    A string, or regular expression representing the set of strings,
    that, given doesRecognizeDelimitedSubstrings === true, delimit
    mentionExternalValue substrings that can also serve as external
    value of the mention if yielded by a modification of
    mentionExternalValue
```