# How can I get the caret position on a contenteditable <button>

Tags: javascript, button, contenteditable, caret

So I have a contenteditable button in my webpage I declare like so:

```
<button id="test" contentEditable="true">This <img src="image..png" /> is a button, click me!</button>
```

I move the caret around, and I want to find its final location. I tried both:

- window.getSelection().focusOffset.toString()
- document.getElementById('test').selectionStart.toString()";

but neither of them seems to work :( Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Unfortunately the code from the links below seems to work only with Firefox and not with Chrome (for a `button`, `div`s work just fine)

---

Take a look at these:

- [Get caret position in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div)
- https://niichavo.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/contenteditable-div-cursor-position/

Here's a [quick and dirty fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/pu6sh/) - it isn't perfect but it might help you get started. I've used code from the blog post at the second link above.

Comment: Hey nogood, I looked at the first example on SO for the caret position, it works for contenteditable div but not button. I saw your code snippet. Did you try executing it? It didn't work for me...

Comment: @Freakishly, I just tried it again, it works fine in FF4 but doesn't work in Chrome.