# div search form with formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a syntax highlighted search field, where certain items are a particular color, bold, underline, etc. when I type. As I type, I would like the word `in` to become bold. This works with what I currently have, but when `in` is typed the cursor goes to the beginning of the div, and you can't type anything after the word `in` either. What can I do to fix this? You can see the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ok4of8e/).

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#q", function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    val = val.replace(/\sin\s/ig, " <b>in</b> ");
    $(this).html(val);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="q" name="q" class="form-control input-lg" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, the first thing I would try is get the cursor position at the beginning of the function and put it back there at the end of the function.

Comment: See [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) - specifically [`.getRangeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt) and [`.addRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange).

Comment: I found this for getting the position: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976125/1778465 and I found this for setting it http://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/1778465, the second on is giving me this error though: `Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 12 is larger than or equal to the node's length (9).`

Comment: here is a possible working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpatik/3QAeC/

Answer (score 0):

With the [rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) I was able to accomplish this like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#q", function(){
    var savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
    var val = $(this).html();
    val = val.replace(/\sin\s/ig, " <b>in</b> ");
    $(this).html(val);
    rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel);
});
```