# How to get cursor position in a contenteditable div inside shadow-dom?

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom

I am trying to implement a custom text-editor functionality inside shadow-dom. And I need to get the current cursor position inside the contenteditable div.

I have already tried a couple of methods. But none of them gave the desired output.

Comment: Please find the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/stormraider2495/pen/GbZzWE?editors=0010

Comment: Possible dupluicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976125/4051471

Comment: I have already gone through that and attached the codepen for it as well.
But I need to get the cursor position within a shadow-dom.
The code always returns 0 when implemented inside of shadow-dom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get caret position in contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972014/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div)

Comment: what is the relation with Shadow DOM?

Comment: In shadowDom window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) always returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `window.getSelection`, use the shadowRoot element which you will need to pass in as an argument to `getCaretPosition`. Assuming you have `getCaretPosition(shadowRoot)`, then the code changes to `shadowRoot.getSelection`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot for functionality available on the ShadowRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as,

```js
/*
style="-webkit-user-select:text;" is needed for iPad

*/
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
  var caretOffset = 0;
  var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel;
  if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    }
  } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    var textRange = sel.createRange();
    var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
    preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
    preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
    caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
  }
  return caretOffset;
}

function getCaretPosition() {
  if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedObj = window.getSelection();
    var rangeCount = 0;
    var childNodes = selectedObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (childNodes[i] == selectedObj.anchorNode) {
        break;
      }
      if (childNodes[i].outerHTML)
        rangeCount += childNodes[i].outerHTML.length;
      else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        rangeCount += childNodes[i].textContent.length;
      }
    }
    return range.startOffset + rangeCount;
  }
  return -1;
}

function showCaretPos(event) { // event parameter added 
  // This is the position object of pointer
  var obj = {x : event.clientX,
                 y : event.clientY};
                 
  console.log(obj);
                 
  var el = document.getElementById("test");
  var caretPosEl = document.getElementById("caretPos");
  caretPosEl.innerHTML = "Caret position: " +
    getCaretPosition();
  getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(el);
}

document.body.onkeyup = showCaretPos;
document.body.onmouseup = showCaretPos;
```

```html
Non-editable text. Editable is below:
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="-webkit-user-select:text;">Hello, some <b>bold</b> and <i>italic and <b>bold</b></i> text</div>
<div id="caretPos"></div>
```