# How to get cursor position in contenteditable div including HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a program where I need the position of the cursor in an editable div, and tags should be counted as well.

Example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>Text here!</p>
</div>
```

If the cursor is placed after "Text", the cursor position should be 7, not 4. This happens when the HTML tag is included.

Solutions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128599/12834165, only count the visible characters, resulting in the output being 4.