# Rangy + ContentEditable + Set Caret and Replace Selection

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, rangy

I have the following fragment of code to set the caret to a given index `index`

```
var el = $("#subjectMessage"), index = 9 ;
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.setStart(el[0].childNodes[0], index);
range.collapse(true);
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.setSingleRange(range);
```

Issues arise when I add input elements to the contentEditable `div`, I can't consistently set the caret at the desired position anymore.

I want to treat these inputs as just one position in the div (as if they were just a single character).

Aside from this, I also would need similar code to replace the selection within this contentEditable `div` with some text of my own, and I'm not really familiar (*at all*) with rangy to understand how to make this work...

All help is desperately welcome!

Here's a fiddle you can toy with:

http://jsfiddle.net/ee93P/

Comment: `I want to treat these inputs as just one position in the div (as if they were just a single character).` It works that way for me, in Firefox.

Comment: Yup, but the thing is I want to manipulate the div to edit the selection and place the caret where I feel like.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. (Niiice stuff you're working on. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rangy's Selection and Range APIs are supersets of the standard DOM Selection and Range APIs, so documentation from places like MDN ([Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range), [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection)) apply.

The problem you're having is that range boundaries are expressed as an offset within a containing DOM node. For example, in the HTML below where the caret is denoted as a pipe character:

```
<p>Foo<br>b|ar</p>
```

... the caret range's start and end boundaries are identical and are set to offset 1 in the text node "bar".

If you wanted to set the position as an offset within the text content of the `<p>` element, you would need to do some DOM traversal. I've written an implementation of this, based on [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596688/96100). This is naive implementation: it does not take into account any text that may be made invisible (either by CSS or by being inside a  or  element, for example) and may have browser discrepancies (IE versus everything else) with line breaks, and takes no account of collapsed whitespace (such as 2 or more consecutive space characters collapsing to one visible space on the page). This is a tricky thing to get right, which is why I wouldn't generally recommend it. I am planning to write a text-based module for Rangy that will handle all this, but I haven't started it yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/ee93P/2/

Code:

```
function setCaretCharIndex(containerEl, index) {
    var charIndex = 0, stop = {};

    function traverseNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (index >= charIndex && index <= nextCharIndex) {
                rangy.getSelection().collapse(node, index - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        }
        // Count an empty element as a single character. The list below may not be exhaustive.
        else if (node.nodeType == 1
                 && /^(input|br|img|col|area|link|meta|link|param|base)$/i.test(node.nodeName)) {
            charIndex += 1;
        } else {
            var child = node.firstChild;
            while (child) {
                traverseNodes(child);
                child = child.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        traverseNodes(containerEl);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex != stop) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I do something similar, to get the selected range in this same div?

Comment: @Nico: You could adapt the `saveSelection()` function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595956/replace-innerhtml-in-contenteditable-div/5596688#5596688. If I get a moment, I'll try to look at it.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you sir, I'll give +1 to all your answers :D