# How can I style text input as I type?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every time I type a character in an input field, I parse the expression so that I get:

1. An array of tokens, i.e., tokenArray=[2, *, COS, (, 4, )]
2. A corresponding array of token types, i.e.,  tokenType=[NUMBER, OPERATOR, FUNCTION, (, NUMBER, )]

I need to style each token (for instance assigning a different color to each token) based on its respective token type.

I have been able to easily style a dynamic copy of the input text in a different `<div>` (not the input text itself, which is what I am asking for help) as follows:

JavaScript:

```javascript
function processExpression() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('inputText').value;

        var resultOutput =  parse(userInput); //this generates the two arrays described above

        for (i in tokenArray) 
          newHTML += "<span style='color: " + colorMap[ tokenType[i] ] + " '>" +  tokenArray[i] + "</span>";

          document.getElementById('styledExpression').innerHTML = newHTML; 
}
```

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="inputText" value="" placeholder="Type expression" size="40"
        onKeyDown="processExpression();" 
        onKeyUp="processExpression();"/>

<div id="styledExpression" value=""></div>
```

How can I style the input text directly in the input field where I type?
Any JavaScript solution?

UPDATE

Tim's answer to the question [replace innerHTML in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595956/replace-innerhtml-in-contenteditable-div/10493141#10493141) provides some good help.

How would you modify http://jsfiddle.net/2rTA5/2/ to solve for when at every keydown, one reparses the entire editable? For example, imagine you type "=if(AND(3=2,A1:A4,OR(0,1)),5,6)" and, at every keydown the editable  gets programmatically re-written (see token description above) and I lose the cursor.

How can this solution ignore the type of token or character or node and simply save and restore the absolute cursor (from the beginning of the ) position that was before the keydown?

Comment: I actually just started working on something like this a couple hours ago! It's not easy, but what I have so far might help you get started: https://github.com/minitech/OpenEdit

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try making the `<input>` transparent and styling things behind it. This works best for background colors, but you can also make the text transparent to get simple styling effects.

Answer (score 6):

Text inputs do not support styled content. End of story.

A common solution is to use [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) instead.

Comment: Good job linking to it, it makes all the difference. :)

Comment: +1 for </of story> ...Matt Ball... the man with a plan (100.000) :)

Answer (score 4):

as Matt said, `<input>`s don't support styling content. However, one possible solution could be to use a second `<span>` that will contain the input's value, and show the styled content here. If that's not acceptable, then use `contenteditable` as Matt suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of hack styling behind it if it's just for unimportant aesthetics.

- Make the background and the text of the `<input>` transparent
- Have another `<span>` behind it
- Update the content of the `<span>` (with appropriate styling) when the `<input>`'s contents change

[Here's a quick demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/Ku3yc/)

Comment: Simple and effective solution. Is there a way to see the cursor and avoid the blue border? Thanks

Comment: @Gian: Blue border? I'm not sure what you mean there... as for the cursor, there's no cross-browser solution, I'm afraid. If you only need it for WebKit, use `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`; otherwise, you'll pretty much have to style it using background colors and nothing else.

Comment: I meant the blue sky around the div field (the standard border showing focus on the element)

Comment: @Gian: Sure, just set `outline: none` on the `<input>`.