# Preserve caret position in contenteditable when unwrapping element?

Tags: jquery, selection, contenteditable, rangy

I have this problem which I have tried to show in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYmHj/). I have contenteditable in which is simple html - just text and one `<B>` element. My question is about situation when the caret is somewhere inside `<B>` element and user hits "X" key. Then the `<B>` element is succesfully unwrapped, but caret changes position and moves to the beginning of the unwrapped `<B>` element.

I want the caret to not change its position and stay in the samoe position. Is it possible ? Preferrably solution by using [Rangy library](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) ?

The code is simplified for purpose of this question:

```
<div id="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">
  text text text text <b>bold bold bold</b> text text text
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#contenteditable').bind('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.which == 88) {
      $('#contenteditable').find('b').contents().unwrap();
    }
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest storing the caret position as a character index within the text inside your `contenteditable` element. The same code that I linked to in an answer to a recent question of yours would do:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10682429/96100

Comment: Wow, that is just so ingenious. Never thought it would be so easy. I've tried many difficult ways, but this is simple brilliant :-) Thanks!

Comment: Simple?! where is the simple part in this?

Comment: Tim, any idea why when i delete all of the characters in a `contenteditable` (this might not be due to the fact that it is `contenteditable`) element, the caret position moves to the top of the parent container, whereas when there are characters they are vertically centered using `flex` `align-items`?