# IHTMLTxtRange.pastHTML limit?

Tags: c#, html, dom, browser, webbrowser-control

I have the following problem. I have to find a phrase in html document and surround each word in the phrase in a span element. I'm searching with this code:

```
        var range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(body);
        var i = 0;
        do
        {
            range.findText(note.Text, range.text.Length, 0);
            i++;
            if (i < note.Occurence)
                range.moveStart("character", 1);
        } while (i != note.Occurence);
```

Then I surround every word in range.text with a span element and I try to replace original phrase with the one surrounded by spans. 
Everything works fine if the phrase contains only one or a few words, but when the phrase is big, my spans are not inserted in html at all. for example, when I try to paste the following html in range:

```
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ძნელი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>საშოვარი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>შეიქმნა</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>და</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გამომცემელსაც</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მისი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გამოსვლის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ვადა</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გამოცხადებულიჰქონდა,</span> 
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ამიტომ,</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>რომ</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>დაპირება</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>არ</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>დარღვეულიყო,</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>წიგნის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ბეჭდვის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>შეწყვეტა</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>და</span> 
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მწერლობისა,ხელოვნებისა</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>და</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ეკონომიური</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მდგომარეობის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მიმოხილვის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>შემცველი</span> 
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>უკანასკნელი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ნაწილის</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მეორეწიგნში</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გადატანა</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>აუცილებელი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გახდა.</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ამ</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გარემოების</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გამო</span> 
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>უკანასკნელ</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>თავში</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მოყვანილიზოგიერთი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>დებულების</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>გაგება</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>ძნელი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>იქნება,</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>რადგან</span> 
<span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>მაშინდელი</span> <span id='0' style='background-color:gray' class='Annotation'>სხვადასხვა</span>
```

span elements are stripped off from the document and I get plain text. Any idea why is this happening? 
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

After doing some more tests, looks like passing existing html (without modification) markup to pasteHtml breaks the output (and inserts `<br>` tags for unknown reason).

Comment: Anyone can explain why the downvote please? :/

Comment: I can't explain why it was down-voted, but I don't have an answer ready, either. Try to find the offending tag in what you're pasting, by starting with a much smaller fragment and adding more tags to it, one by one.

Comment: I already did it. The output is a valid generated html. I can save it in a html file and it renders correctly in the browser. However, when I examine the range where I used pasteHtml, the tags are not there, only plain text and a few <BR> tags which aren't supposed to be there.

Comment: If you like to take this any further, create a simple repro fiddle with jsfiddle.net and post a link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pasteHtml is a bit buggy. I found the solution by acquiring range parent element via range.parentElement() and manipulating it's innerHtml (replace, append etc).