# Change colour of text on keydown up to space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contenteditable div. What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the user types the `@` symbol, it (on keypress) changes the colour of the text (including the `@` symbol) until the next space.

For example, imagine that the bold text is the coloured text:

"Here is some **@sample** text."

Here's the JSFiddle I started, but I don't know how to carry on from it: http://jsfiddle.net/p8WsT/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="typeable" contenteditable="true">Type "@test" after this text: </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".typeable", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var code = event.keyCode; // code 50 is @
});
```

Please help!

Comment: The answers for this similar question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107150/jquery-javascript-syntax-highlighting-as-user-types-in-contenteditable-region

Comment: @user3739658 Share what you've got so far, maybe someone else can work off it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple example thrown together to help you get started: http://jsfiddle.net/wB6k5/

It uses `selection` and `range` to select words and then I run `execCommand` on the selection.

[MDN Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
[MDN execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand)

There's an event listener on the key up event to check to see if we need to run the highlight function.

```
var userPressedAt = false;

function highlight() {
    var el = $('.typeable')[0],
        str = $('.typeable').text(),
        range = document.createRange(),
        sel = window.getSelection(),
        start,
        end;

    start = str.lastIndexOf('@');
    end = str.length;

    // Assumes single line
    range.setStart(el.childNodes[0], start);
    range.setEnd(el.childNodes[0], end);

    sel.addRange(range);

    el.focus();

    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, 'red');

}

function highlighter(e) { console.log(e.which);
    // user typed @ - wait for space to highlight
    if (e.which === 64) {
        userPressedAt = true;
    }

    if (userPressedAt && e.which === 32) {
        highlight();
    }
}

$('.typeable').on('keyup', highlighter);
```

Again, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wB6k5/

It's not nearly complete (typing another `@username` won't work, for instance - looks like we need to clear the range) but hopefully it helps you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("keydown keyup", ".typeable", function (event) {
    // 50: `@`, 32: `spacebar`
    // if (event.which === 50 || event.which === 32) {
    $(this).html(function (i, o) {
        var _o = $(this).text();
        var bold = _o.replace(/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, function (b) {
            return "<b>" + b + "</b>";
        });
        return bold
    })
    .on("focus", function (e) {
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" 
           && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(e.target);
            range.collapse(false);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(e.target);
            textRange.collapse(false);
            textRange.select();
        };
    }).focus();
    // end `if`
    // };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/wLqTA/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107150/jquery-javascript-syntax-highlighting-as-user-types-in-contenteditable-region , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div