# How to set the caret at the end of the input in my case(specific)?

Tags: html, colors, contenteditable, caret

My problem is very specific, im trying to create online code editor with colored scripts.
Im using `contenteditable` `div` so i can add `span`. When im typing the word `script` the `caret` is going at the begining of the field, and each time i try add more text the caret again is going at the begining.

If someone helps me to fix this it will help to many people who is trying to do that.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div contentEditable style="width: 400px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("input", function() {
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML= document.querySelector("div").innerHTML
.replace("script","<span style='color:red;'>script</span>");
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595956/replace-innerhtml-in-contenteditable-div http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376/96100

Comment: when im using your code to do that : 

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("script", "<font style='color: red;'>script</font>");

all the code after "script" word is in red?? why??

Comment: Have you got a demo page I can see?

Comment: Tim i want to ask you because you are professional. Is there any way to make textarea with line numbers with pure Javascript. I don't need any jQuery code, ajax or plugin. I want to learn how to do that with pure javascript. Can you please assist me?!