# Detect if you type inside a span tag

Tags: jquery, hashtag

Hello and thanks for taking your time to read this.

If have the following function below, that highlight `#` and `@` when I write in the textbox.

When I/User type on of the Hightlight keys(**@** / **#**), It createds a `<span> tag` around it. When the use make a space it stops the hightlight

My question is, how can I check if I type while inside the `<span> tag`, because I need something to happen while a use type something like `@this` or `#this`and then stop when the use hit the space key.

I hope you understand my Question and I thank you for your time.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hashtags = function () {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="Hashtags"><div class="highlighter"></div></div>').unwrap().before('<div class="highlighter"></div>').wrap('<div class="typehead"></div></div>');
        $(this).addClass("theSelector");
        autosize($(this));
        $(this).on("keyup", function () {
            var str = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").css("width", $(this).css("width"));
            str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
            if (!str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g)) {
                if (!str.match(/#(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))#/g)) { //arabic support
                    str = str.replace(/#(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))/g, '<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
                } else {
                    str = str.replace(/#(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))#(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))/g, '<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
                }
                if (!str.match(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))@/g)) {
                    str = str.replace(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))/g, '<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
                } else {
                    str = str.replace(/@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([\u0600-\u06FF]+))/g, '<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
                }
            }
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").html(str);
        });
        $(this).parent().prev().on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".theSelector").focus();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
            $("textarea").hashtags();
  });
```

```css
.Hashtags .highlighter{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
 color:transparent;
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: absolute;
 padding-left:7px;
 padding-top:5px; 
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:20px;
}

.Hashtags .theSelector{
 background-color: transparent; 
 position: relative; 
 direction: ltr; 
 font-size:14px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 resize:none !important;
 -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 4px 6px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 min-height:48px !important;
 line-height:20px;
}

.Hashtags .hashtag{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#dce6f8, #bdcff1);
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #a3bcea;
 font-size:14px;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 word-break: break-word;
 line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/js/autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <textarea style="width: 250px; min-height: 100px!important;"></textarea>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you make your code so complicated. Do you have other html things inside the textarea? If you don't have why you dont just get the whole textarea (jquery .text()) and than add the span for every entry that starts with @ or # and stops when it hits a space or the end of the file.

Comment: can you even wrap text inside a `textarea` in an actual `span`? I think you must use contenteditable `div` for that

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/2rTA5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596688/1449710) I found a jsfiddle which uses the rangy.js library. [I modified the script a bit and it wraps all strings of the pattern `@string`](http://jsfiddle.net/2rTA5/244/) in a `font` element, but you can adjust to your needs :-)

The full code:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="pad" onkeyup="formatText();"></div>
```

JS:

```
function saveSelection(containerEl) {
    var charIndex = 0, start = 0, end = 0, foundStart = false, stop = {};
    var sel = rangy.getSelection(), range;

    function traverseTextNodes(node, range) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (!foundStart && node == range.startContainer) {
                start = charIndex + range.startOffset;
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && node == range.endContainer) {
                end = charIndex + range.endOffset;
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex += node.length;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i], range);
            }
        }
    }

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        try {
            traverseTextNodes(containerEl, sel.getRangeAt(0));
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex != stop) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}

function restoreSelection(containerEl, savedSel) {
    var charIndex = 0, range = rangy.createRange(), foundStart = false, stop = {};
    range.collapseToPoint(containerEl, 0);

    function traverseTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        traverseTextNodes(containerEl);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex == stop) {
            rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}


function formatText() {
    var el = document.getElementById('pad');
    var savedSel = saveSelection(el);
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(\@[0-9a-z]+)/ig,"<font color='red'>$1</font>");

    // Restore the original selection
    restoreSelection(el, savedSel);
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2rTA5/244/)