# Chrome extension dom replaceChild freezes the page

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension to mark some words on the current page.

I have asked another question on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801525/how-to-wrap-part-of-all-text-node-nodevalue-in-an-html-element) to achieve this. The solution is valid but not working for my extension somehow. The replaceChild line makes the page freeze.

Why is this happening ? How can I fix this ? Any workarounds are welcomed.

here is what I have so far for my content_script javascript file content.js :

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j],
            par = node.parentElement;

        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            replacer(node, par);
        }
    }
}

function replacer (node, parent) {
    var re = /Questions/;
    var str = node.nodeValue;

    if (re.exec(str) !== null) {
        var newNode = document.createElement('span');

        newNode.innerHTML = node
            .nodeValue
            .replace(/Questions/g, '<span>$&</span>');

        console.log('should replace child here !');
        parent.replaceChild(newNode, node);
    }
}
```

everything works fine but this line(comment the line to see) :

```
parent.replaceChild(newNode, node);
```

here is manifest.json :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Search Hero",
    "description": "blablabla",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at":    "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you confirmed that the `parent` and `node` params are indeed correct.

Comment: I cannot see any error because the page freezes. The parent and node are correct(I tried commenting replaceChild and everything worked fine)

Comment: @AlexB Why don't use use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)? Using `innerHTML` will trigger regeneration of the DOM and destroys events!

Comment: @dude I have seen mark.js, I think I will use it. It is made for that. Would I really destroy events ? I am only  adding a span inside other elements... I am not sure. But yeah, the question is still interesting for me but you are right, I should definitely use mark.js

Comment: @AlexB Yes, it indeed does destroy all events. Read more e.g. here http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/